# ASP .NET MVC or XMLHttpRequest limit?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I upload file in angularjs app with [angular-file-upload](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)

Have two upload

1. upload ok

Content-Length:3515744

Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryBw0EMfNfB9biF4Kn

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="x.mp4"

Content-Type: video/mp4

1. upload error 500

Content-Length:4551690

Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryPW4QWcJZAlYPBOb6

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="y.mp4"

Content-Type: video/mp4

*ExceptionMessage
:
"Sequence contains no elements"
ExceptionType
:
"System.InvalidOperationException"*

code

```cs
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).
            ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(o =>
            {
                MultipartFileData file = (MultipartFileData)provider.FileData.First();
```

1. request

```cs
provider.FileData.Count = 1
```

2. request

```cs
provider.FileData.Count = 0
```

web.config

```xml
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483647" />
    <fileExtensions>
       <add fileExtension=".mp4" allowed="true" />
    </fileExtensions>
```

Where i can change limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following set the upload limit,

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
```